# How do I place two or more ASCII images side by side?

Tags: python

I wish to build a series of card games. The idea is to place ASCII images of cards into dictionary values to be called whenever they are needed. However, I cannot figure out how to get the cards to print out side by side, no matter which method that I use.

I have tried solving this using the `for`-loop, `join` and by modifying the `print` function. Each time the output produces:

```
.-------.
|A      |
|       |
|   ♣   |
|       |
|      A|
`-------´

.-------.
|2      |
|       |
|   ♦   |
|       |
|      2|
`-------´
```

instead of:

```
.-------.  .-------.
|A      |  |2      |
|       |  |       |
|   ♣   |  |   ♦   |
|       |  |       |
|      A|  |      2|
`-------´  `-------´
```

I think that the problem has something to do with the cursor staying at the bottom of the image instead of returning to the top of the image.
I have spent a few hours searching to find information on this, but have produced no results.

Here are two sample variables in a dictionary:

```
ace = r'''
.-------.
|A      |
|       |
|   ♣   |
|       |
|      A|
`-------´
'''

two = r'''
.-------.
|2      |
|       |
|   ♦   |
|       |
|      2|
`-------´
'''
cards = {"Ace":ace, "Two":two}

# modify the print
print(f'{cards["Ace"]} {cards["Two"]}', end=' ')

# using join
space = " "
deck = space.join(cards.values())
print(deck)

# placing the dictionary entries into a list
cards2 = [cards["Ace"], cards["Two"]]
for item in cards2:
    print (item)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lines of the two cards together and print one of each card on each line:

```
ace = r'''\
.-------.
|A      |
|       |
|   ♣   |
|       |
|      A|
`-------´
'''

two = r'''\
.-------.
|2      |
|   ♦   |
|       |
|   ♦   |
|      2|
`-------´
'''

spacer = ' ' * 5  # Space between cards.
for a, b in zip(ace.splitlines(), two.splitlines()):
    print(f'{a}{spacer}{b}')
```

Output:

```
.-------.     .-------.
|A      |     |2      |
|       |     |   ♦   |
|   ♣   |     |       |
|       |     |   ♦   |
|      A|     |      2|
`-------´     `-------´
```

#### Update:

Here's a generalized version for two or more cards:

```
ace = r'''\
.-------.
|A      |
|       |
|   ♣   |
|       |
|      A|
`-------´
'''

two = r'''\
.-------.
|2      |
|   ♦   |
|       |
|   ♦   |
|      2|
`-------´
'''

three = r'''\
.-------.
|3      |
|   ♥   |
|   ♥   |
|   ♥   |
|      3|
`-------´
r'''

spacing = ' ' * 5  # Between cards.
cards = ace, two, three

for pieces in zip(*(card.splitlines() for card in cards)):
    print(spacing.join(pieces))
```

Output:

```
.-------.     .-------.     .-------.
|A      |     |2      |     |3      |
|       |     |   ♦   |     |   ♥   |
|   ♣   |     |       |     |   ♥   |
|       |     |   ♦   |     |   ♥   |
|      A|     |      2|     |      3|
`-------´     `-------´     `-------´
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align them, you're going to have to print by text line rather than by card (so, retrieve the first line of text representing each card, print that first line, and so on).

The code below is an example of that, and assumes all cards are represented by the same number of lines of text:

```py
def print_cards(card_dict, sep="\t"):
    card_lines = [card.split("\n") for card in card_dict.values()]
    for line_num in range(len(lines[0])):
        for card_line in lines: 
            print(card_line[line_num], end="")
            print(sep, end="")
        print()
```

The results are as expected:

```py
>>> print_cards(cards)  
.-------.   .-------.   
|A      |   |2      |   
|       |   |       |   
|   ♣   |   |   ♦   |   
|       |   |       |   
|      A|   |      2|   
`-------´   `-------´
```

Comment: This solution is also a viable answer. It is too bad that I cannot mark this as a solution as well.  You have my thanks! :)