# Is there a way to print a list of user defined objects (each object is a multilined string) on one line?

Tags: python, list, printing, formatting

I am working on a Arithmetic-Formatter excercice (Python 3).
I've defined a class object (problem), where each problem is a string of 4 lines, arranged_problems is a list of problems.

So far this is print statement= `print(*arranged_problems,sep='\n')` and it returns:

```
   32
+ 698
-----
  730

   38
- 299
-----
 -261

  45
+ 43
----
  88
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
   32          38         45
+ 698       - 299       + 43
-----       -----       ----
  730        -261         88
```

Some of what i have tried so far (be careful some reek of desperation/frustration so might seem silly):

```
print(*arranged_problems,sep='\n')
print("{}  {} {}".format(arranged_problems[0],arranged_problems[1],arranged_problems[3]))
print("{}".format(arranged_problems))
print(*arranged_problems,end='')
print(f'the list is: {arranged_problems}')
```

I have also tried list comprehension/loops, the result is pretty much the same, the list is still printed on multiple lines, also the end parameter seems to only apply on the first line.

```
Reproducible example =
a='''   32
+ 698
-----
  730'''
b='''   38
- 299
-----
 -261
'''
c='''  45
+ 43
----
  88
'''
arranged_problems=[]
arranged_problems.append(a)
arranged_problems.append(b)
arranged_problems.append(c)
print(*arranged_problems,sep='\n')
```

Would anyone be so kind to share some insight/functions/libraries/links that might help?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the response @martineau , I just added one.

Comment: Yep, thought that might be what the `arranged_problems` were.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795576/388066 might give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you! the link you provided does help a lot.