# How to display an object?

Tags: python

I code that to create a card game.

```
class JeuDeCarte: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.contenu = []
        self.j1 = []
        self.j2 = []
        self.CreerJeu()

    def CreerJeu(self):
        for color in couleur:
            for number in numero:
                self.contenu.append(Carte(number,color))

    def melanger(self): 
        return shuffle(self.contenu)

    def TailleJeu(self): 
        return(len(self.contenu))

    def PaquetVide(self) : 
        return self.contenu ==[] #Renvoie True si il est vide, False sinon
        
    def AfficherPaquet(self):
        return self.contenu

jeu = JeuDeCarte()
jeu.melanger()
jeu.distribuer()
print(jeu.AfficherPaquet())
```

But when I run this code, I have this:

```
[<__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c820>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d7c0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48da90>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d1c0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d610>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d340>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d670>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c8e0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47ca00>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c9a0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cee0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47ce20>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d4f0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d220>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cac0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d2e0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cca0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d5b0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d130>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d550>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47ce80>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d940>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d9a0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c730>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d880>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d040>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cfa0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c940>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cb80>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c790>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d8e0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d6d0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d460>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d280>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48da00>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cd00>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cb20>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cf40>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d0a0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d3a0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d760>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47c880>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d700>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cdc0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d400>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d820>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48daf0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d48d490>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cd60>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47ca60>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cbe0>, <__main__.Carte object at 0x7f206d47cc40>]
```

How to correct that?

Comment: I already tried but it returned the same thing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your `Carte` class.

Comment: It's `__repr__` that you need here, not `__str__`.

Comment: You may (also) find [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795265/how-do-i-place-two-or-more-ascii-images-side-by-side/69795576#69795576) to [How do I place two or more ASCII images side by side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795265/how-do-i-place-two-or-more-ascii-images-side-by-side) of interest.